# jquery validation with form inside tabs

Tags: jquery, html, validation

i have 2 tabs that has input form inside these tabs(the tabs is inside 1 form). in the first tabs the input is required and the second one isn't. lets say i didn't fill the first input and i am on the second tabs. and when i submit the form, the validation on the first tabs doesn't work. and it will submit the form

here is my html:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#price" data-toggle="tab">Price</a></li>
        <li><a href="#category" data-toggle="tab">Category</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content m-t">
        <div id="price" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('price','Price',array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}<span><strong> * :</strong></span>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Rp</span>
                        {!! Form::text('price', null, array('class' => 'form-control currency_inputx rupiah', 'required' => 'required') + $extraAttributes) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="category" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('category','Category',array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}<span><strong> * :</strong></span>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Rp</span>
                        {!! Form::text('category', null, array('class' => 'form-control currency_inputx rupiah') + $extraAttributes) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

please help me thanks!

Comment: I think that if an input is in "display: none" (or its parent), then you can submit the form even if it's not filled (but required). Maybe you should try to make your tabs work without setting one of them in display: none ?

Comment: Is the input visible on that tab?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz the input display stay the same, but the `<div id="price" class="tab-pane fade in active">` display changes to none when not active